# Solicitar contraseña administrador para realizar cierta operacion php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sesiones

Hago un desarrollo, en el cual existen 2 tipo de usuarios (user y admin). 
Cada uno entra sus carpetas especificas, pero hay momentos, en el cual un user, necesita la contraseña de admin para realizar cierta operacion que va mas alla de los permisos que se puedan otorgar.

Ya hice la operacion de solicitar formulario de ingreso de password al entrar a este modulo, pero mi gran problema es: como hago para que una vez ingresada la contraseña de admin, la sesion de admin se mantenga solo para este proceso, de manera que el admin ponga la contraseña y el user realice el proceso que necesite y una vez hecho esto, cierre la sesion admin y siga la sesion user normalmente?.

Cabe señalar, que este form y proceso restringido, se realiza a traves de un modal boostrap y la idea que es todo este proceso, se realice en ese modal.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que no estaría bien hacer lo que dices. Un Admin es un Admin y no le puede *prestar*  su acceso a un usuario de nivel inferior. Imagina lo que eso supone a nivel de responsabilidades. El cardiólogo no le puede prestar el bisturí a un enfermero en una operación del corazón, así de sencillo, el enfermero puede cortar una vena y mata al paciente. Quizá necesites otro nivel de acceso en tu sistema, algo así como un nivel `Editor` o algo así... algo intermedio entre un usuario básico y un admin.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tus consejos. efectivamente, es una gran vulnerabilidad hacer eso, por lo mismo, optare por otro nivel de acceso como me planteas. saludos

Comment: Podrias hacer que durante el proceso que este realizando el usuario darle los permisos especificos para ese proceso o funcion, cuando finalice le retiras estos permisos. Asi solo tendra acceso en un momento dado.

Comment: @LombardaArda es una idea que estaba manejando desde un principio para este problema, pero opte por agregar un privilegio mas en donde el admin decide que modulos pueden usar los demas usuarios. Gracias de todas maneras por tu consejo. saludos

Answer (score 0):

para no abrir huecos en la seguridad ni sobrescribir la sesión, podrías manejar dicha operación con permisos (privilegios), donde para abrir el modal que dices, se necesite un permiso que previamente otorgas al usuario para esa operación. así no comprometes la seguridad del administrador ni del sistema en si.
Suerte!

Comment: efectivamente, optare por no correr riesgos en la seguridad de los modulos y creare nuevos permisos para este tipo de cosas. un saludo y gracias por tu consejo.